# R t.test on subset of database

Tags: r

I'l trying to do t.test on subsets of my database.
Here is my standard test, which works very well on the whole sample:

```
t.test(db$cervicalesint~db$Sexe,data=db)
```

Following my former Stata user logic, I tried the most intuitive condition: "if", only to get rejected cause "if" only works on logical variables and my variables are all factors:

```
if (db$doul==1) t.test(db$cervicalesint~db$Sexe,data=db)
```

Warning message:
In if (db$doul == 1) t.test(db$cervicalesint ~ db$Sexe, data = db) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Since I saw no other way to get past this using a condition (tried ifelse only to get the same problem, + I have no else so it seems counter-intuitive), I tried to use the subset argument like this:

```
t.test(db$cervicalesint~db$Sexe,data=db, subset(db$doul, db$doul==1) )
```

Error in t.test.formula(db$cervicalesint ~ db$Sexe, data = db, subset(db$doul,  : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

I'm pretty sure I'm making a syntax mistake in "subset(db$doul, db$doul==1)" which create an empty subset, but I don't know how to write it right.
db$doul is of Numeric type, shown in the db as:
doul : Factor w/ 2 levels "No", "Yes": 111112222

So 2 questions:
-Is this the best way to make tests on subsamples? I'm asking because subset is not available for the other syntax of t.test(var1, var2) and I'll have to use that too.

-What is the right way to write this code?

Thanks

Comment: You need to insert the subset for `db` in `data=db`. Ergo, `t.test(db$cervicalesint ~ db$Sexe, data = subset(db, db$doul == 1))`. Or, easier, subset with `[`, as in `data = db[db$doul == 1, ]`.

Comment: For future reference, please make sure your code is reproducible. This means people can catch issues like data type mismatches, encoding, etc. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, so I tried it using the suggested options and I don't get any error, but subsetting does not seem to work. Here is my code (reproductible this time using the CO2 base from R): t.test(CO2$uptake~CO2$type, data=CO2[CO2$treatment==1,]). It gives the exact same result as using data=CO2, so I think the subsetting is not done. I got the same result using my database.

Comment: After a few more tests: I did not manage to use subset to test on a part of my sample. However, I managed to do what I wanted by creating a new database using subset, and using the new variables generated (subset$type instead of CO2$type for example). And what mattered was the variables names, not the data t.test targetted to.

Comment: Last comment: by explaining it to you I finally understood. My mistake was using CO2$type and not type in my formula. The CO2$ went over the data=subset. Thanks for guiding me!